# Artifactory javax.crypto.BadPaddingException error when Deactivate Artifactory Key Encryption

Tags: artifactory

I'm attempting to Deactivate Artifactory Key Encryption (as suggested when [upgrading to 5.9](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Artifactory5.9)).

I use the [documented REST api](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeactivateArtifactoryKeyEncryption):

```
curl -X POST "http://artifactory-qa/artifactory/api/system/decrypt" -u ***:***
```

but I get the following error:

```
2018-08-30 10:48:38,008 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.i.ApiKeysEncryptor:29) - Starting decryption of all users API Keys
2018-08-30 10:48:39,312 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.i.ApiKeysEncryptor:32) - Finished decryption of all users API Keys
2018-08-30 10:48:39,328 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.i.UserPasswordEncryptor:43) - Starting decryption of all users passwords
2018-08-30 10:48:41,728 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.i.UserPasswordEncryptor:64) - Finished decryption of all users passwords
2018-08-30 10:48:41,764 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] [ERROR] (o.a.r.r.s.SystemResource:157) - Could not decrypt with master key, due to: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
org.jfrog.security.crypto.exception.CryptoRuntimeException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at org.jfrog.security.crypto.KeyFileEncryptionWrapper.decrypt(KeyFileEncryptionWrapper.java:133) ~[jfrog-crypto-1.3.16.jar:na]
    at org.jfrog.security.crypto.KeyFileEncryptionWrapper.decryptIfNeeded(KeyFileEncryptionWrapper.java:95) ~[jfrog-crypto-1.3.16.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.common.crypto.CryptoHelper.decryptIfNeeded(CryptoHelper.java:79) ~[artifactory-config-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.layout.EncryptConfigurationInterceptor.getNewPassword(EncryptConfigurationInterceptor.java:183) ~[artifactory-core-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.layout.EncryptConfigurationInterceptor.encryptOrDecrypt(EncryptConfigurationInterceptor.java:112) ~[artifactory-core-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.layout.EncryptConfigurationInterceptor.decrypt(EncryptConfigurationInterceptor.java:54) ~[artifactory-core-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.ArtifactoryEncryptionServiceImpl.decrypt(ArtifactoryEncryptionServiceImpl.java:184) ~[artifactory-core-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.rest.resource.system.SystemResource.decryptFromMasterKey(SystemResource.java:154) ~[artifactory-rest-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.execute(RepoFilter.java:184) [artifactory-web-application-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doFilter(RepoFilter.java:93) [artifactory-web-application-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.authentication.ArtifactoryAuthenticationFilterChain.lambda$1(ArtifactoryAuthenticationFilterChain.java:133) [artifactory-web-application-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.authentication.ArtifactoryBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.authentication.ArtifactoryAuthenticationFilterChain.doFilter(ArtifactoryAuthenticationFilterChain.java:169) [artifactory-web-application-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.authenticateAndExecute(AccessFilter.java:282) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessFilter.java:206) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:166) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:67) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164) ~[spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80) ~[spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:62) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryFilter.java:128) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.8.10.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:279) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:989) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:845) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore.implDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:399) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore$PBEWithSHA1AndDESede.engineDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:431) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jfrog.security.crypto.JFrogCryptoHelper.decryptSymmetric(JFrogCryptoHelper.java:266) ~[jfrog-crypto-1.3.16.jar:na]
    at org.jfrog.security.crypto.KeyFileEncryptionWrapper.decrypt(KeyFileEncryptionWrapper.java:111) ~[jfrog-crypto-1.3.16.jar:na]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
```

I'm wondering if part of my database is corrupted. Is there something I can do to wipe data so that I'm able to proceed with the upgrade?

I'm using artifactory version 5.8.10, but I've tried this with versions as old as 4.16.0 with the same result.

Comment: The error indicates there is something Artifactory was not able to decrypt using the current key. Perhaps you can share the entire stucktrace from the log, so hopefully we can try and see what is it exactly Artifactory is failing to decrypt.

Comment: @ArielKabov - I've included the entire stacktrace. Does that help? (Sorry for the delay - still a blocker for us, let me know if there's anything else you need).